# Trying to view locally on a cloned repo, running firebase serve, throws 404 Cannot GET/ on localhost:5000...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express

firebase serve throws a 404 Cannot GET/

Im trying to view an app that I cloned from gitlab locally, but am not sure what I am missing. I ran

> npm i

to install all dependencies and I installed firebase globally. When I run

> firebase serve

it says Cannot GET / and throws a 404 in the console

any suggestions?

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

firebase serve should run the app locally, instead i get 404 not found

I think the problem is coming from here, in the firebase.json:

> "hosting": {"public": "dist"

What and where is "dist"?